# value of type integer cannot be converted to datatable vn.net

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to create tree view and some error i can not fix it

```vb
Sub CREATENODE()
    Dim TRN As New TreeNode
    Dim DT As New DataTable
    DT.Clear()
    DT = ACCOUNTTableAdapter.TREE_ACCOUNT()

    For I As Integer = 0 To DT.Rows.Count - 1

        If DT.Rows(I)(9).ToString() = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" Then
            TRN = New TreeNode(DT.Rows(I)(3).ToString() + " " + DT.Rows(I)(4).ToString())

            TRN.Tag = DT.Rows(I)(1).ToString()

            If DT.Rows(I)(7).ToString() <> "0" Then

                TRN.ImageIndex = 0
                TRN.SelectedImageIndex = 0
            Else

                TRN.ImageIndex = 1
                TRN.SelectedImageIndex = 1
            End If



            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(TRN)
        End If
    Next
    ''For Each NODE As TreeNode In TreeView1.Nodes
    ''    CHELD(NODE)
    'Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `ACCOUNTTableAdapter.TREE_ACCOUNT()` and what is it returning?

Comment: TREE_ACCOUNT is aquery in  table Account ((SELECT        ID, GUID, END_ACCOUNT, CODE, NAME, LATIN_NAME, DEBET, CREDIT, COUNT_ACCOUNT, PARENT_ACCOUNT
FROM            ACCOUNT
ORDER BY CODE ))

Comment: Apparently, it returns as Integer instead of a DataTable. Possibly, post that method (or just check what it actually returns as opposed to what it was supposed to return).

Answer (score 0):

This is nonsense

```
 Dim TRN As New TreeNode 
 Dim DT As New DataTable
 DT.Clear()
 DT = ACCOUNTTableAdapter.TREE_ACCOUNT()
```

You create a New TreeNode and then inside the loop you overwrite it with another New one. Just put the Dim inside the loop after the if.

```
Dim TRN = New TreeNode($"{row(3)} {row(4)}")
```

You create a brand new DataTable. Then you clear it when it can't possibly have anything in it. Then you throw it away and assign a different DataTable to it.

Just do

```
Dim DT = ACCOUNTTableAdapter.TREE_ACCOUNT()
```

I have simplified your code by using a For Each loop. Also, I used and interpolated string indicated by the $ preceding the string. Variables can be inserted in place surrounded by braces { }.

As far as the actual problem, you need to create an instance of your table adapter with the New keyword. Then call the appropriate method. A simple application will just use `.GetData`.

```
Private Sub CREATENODE()
    Dim DT = (New ACCOUNTTableAdapter).TREE_ACCOUNT() 'See what intellisense offers. It may be just .GetData
    For Each row As DataRow In DT.Rows
        If row(9).ToString() = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" Then
            Dim TRN = New TreeNode($"{row(3)} {row(4)}")
            TRN.Tag = row(1)
            If row(7).ToString() <> "0" Then
                TRN.ImageIndex = 0
                TRN.SelectedImageIndex = 0
            Else
                TRN.ImageIndex = 1
                TRN.SelectedImageIndex = 1
            End If
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(TRN)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Hint: Why not put the entire row in the `Tag` property. You will have access to all the fields by casting the Tag back to a DataRow.